# Error: Creating users/groups on Nextcloud via API with values from textboxes

Tags: c#, webdav, nextcloud

My first post on stackOverflow...here we go:

I have code that creates users/groups on a nextcloud server with data from a GUI's textboxes. The entity is created but then Visual Studio 2017 throws an error.
Maybe anybody had the same behavior?

Not much done yet. Encountered the error yesterday and only did some searching here on StOv.

```
private void createEntity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string strUserName = this.textBox4.Text;
        string strUserPW = this.textBox5.Text;


        // Connect
        var c = new Client(strNcServer, strNcAdminUser, strNcAdminPw);

        // 
        if (this.radioButton1.Checked == true)
        {
            // User....
            var a = c.CreateUser(strUserName, strUserPW);
            // +groups?
            // PI
            if (this.rbGRPpi.Checked == true) {
                a = c.AddUserToGroup(strUserName, strGroupPI);
                // only PI : admin
                if (this.cbGRPadmin.Checked == true)
                {
                    a = c.AddUserToGroup(strUserName, strGroupAdmin);
                }
            }
            // org
            if (this.rbGRPtws.Checked == true)
            {
                a = c.AddUserToGroup(strUserName, strGroupTWS);
            }
        }
        // group
        if (this.radioButton2.Checked == true)
        {
            var a = c.CreateGroup(this.textBox4.Text);
        }
    }
```

The process results in this error (German language):

> InnerException    {"Fehler in Zeile 1, Position 6. Element \"OCS\" aus Namespace
>   \"http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/owncloudsharp.Types\" wird
>   erwartet.. Gefunden: \"Element\" mit dem Namen \"ocs\", Namespace
>   \"\". "}  System.Exception
>   {System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException}

Answer (score 0):

Seems I found a solution. According to the author's github page (issues) this seems to be a behaviour when using the nuget package of owncloud-sharp. Will give the solution a try and create a build of the project.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Answers should explain the complete solution to the question. Please read Stackoverflow guide to post good answers that may earn you reputation.